# Reading in a tar file from sftp and converting it into gzip on hdfs on the fly

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hdfs, gzip

I am trying to read a tar file from an SFTP location and through manipulation with the stream decompress it and then again compress it into a gz on a hadoop ecosystem. I have compressed a simple file with a text message

> Text in the compressed file.

The file name is `testDataTar.txt.tar` and the text file name inside of it is `testDataTar.txt`. A snippet of the code that does the reading and conversion is provided below:

```
def copyFilesToHdfs(sourceFile: FileObject, fs: FileSystem, targetPath: Path): String = {
   val fileName = sourceFile.getName.getBaseName.replaceAll("tar$", "gz")
   val fis = sourceFile.getContent.getInputStream    
   val is = new TarArchiveInputStream(fis)
   val targetFile = new Path(targetPath, fileName)

   val codec = new GzipCodec
   codec.setConf(new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration())
   val os = new DataOutputStream(codec.createOutputStream(fs.create(targetFile)))

   IOUtils.copy(is, os)

   is.close()
   os.close()
   fis.close()

   fileName
}
```

If if read in the resulting file as follows:

```
val fileContent = Config.sparkContext.textFile(targetFile.toString).first()
```

The contents of the file will be empty (was also checked manually) and I end up with an exception as follows.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection
20:22:42   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1369)
20:22:42   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
20:22:42   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
20:22:42   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
20:22:42   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1366)
```

However, if I simply do the same but with a `fis` skipping the line with `TarArchiveInputStream` and feeding the text file itself, I get perfectly compressed gzip file as the output on the hdfs.

So in summary, I somehow can't transfer the file contents between the .tar and .gz streams. I have tried the same for .zip (`ZipInputStream`) to .gz and the result was the same. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Tar is not a compressed format, it's an archive format for multiple files (zip is a compressed archived format). You first need to tell the inputstream which file you want to read from the archive.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt but the result is the same when I use .zip and  `ZipInputStream`. I get the same error. The resulting .gz archive has one empty file.

Comment: .gz is not an archive.  It is a single compressed file.  You can extract one file from the tar and gzip it, or you can gzip the entire tar file (in which case you might use a plain ol FileInputStream instead of a TarArchiveInputStream).

Comment: Since you haven't selected a file that you want to read from the archive, the Tar/ZipInputStream returns a zero-length file. Look through the javadoc for the correct way to select the file from the archive.